# how to send the latitude and longitude location data to the server

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I have a class GPSTracker to get location . and I want to send the location to a server . I tried this way but failed . but the latitude and longitude remains zero 
http://pastebin.com/e0BJfpVW and this mya GPSTracker class http://pastebin.com/351Ni95h

Comment: Have you got the right `Latlng` data from your GPSTracker?

Comment: yes i show to maps is right

Comment: So there is something went wrong with your data when go to the server. You may use the debug mode to take a look at your class `input` at line 25,26